# QFile text can't output stream

Tags: c++, qt, qfile

```
// .txt
QFile txtFile(":/new/prefix1/saveddata.txt");
if (txtFile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text))
{
    // We're going to streaming text to the file
    QTextStream stream(&txtFile);

    stream << "testing\n";
    stream << "testing\n";

    txtFile.close();
}
```

I have a `QFile`, which I am trying to open from the directory above. The file exists but does not open. Any idea why and how to fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file path specified is a resource path, and resources probably cannot be modified, so the "open for writing" request fails. The [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html) for resources says nothing about writing data to resource files, only reading.

Resources are specifically designed for read-only data, so you need to use some other form of data storage if you want to modify the information.
See [`QSettings`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsettings.html) for an alternative.

Comment: so if wanted to write to an existing textfile, i will have to add the text file in the project and then write?

Comment: No. Any filename starting with a colon (`:`) will specify a resource file included in the project. You can reference a normal file just by using the unchanged filename, escaping backslashes if necessary.